# Add additional attributes to GetMenu2 Options

Tags: php

I currently have an  box using GetMenu2 and is trying to assign additional java scripts to it. I read the website and it says that I can use "$moreAttr to add additional attributes such as javascript or styles." but I cannot get this to work,

php:

```
$info=$rs->GetMenu2('assign_val', $employee,$employee_id);
$smarty->assign('employee', $employee);
```

How can I add additional styles to this or what I really wanted is to add an oncclick event, something like:

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```

Also

output looks like this

```
{$employee} outputs:

<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="assign_val" >
<option value='1'>Sam</option>
<option value='2'>Joe</option>
<option value='3'>Steve</option>
</select>
```

Thanks everyone..

Comment: no one knows anything about this? :(

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by reading page 42 on this page..

http://books.google.com/books?id=QlN84kFPPXkC&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=getmenu2+%3Coption%3E&source=bl&ots=UAoTlAkF8Y&sig=5vGqn0bZDbxbJdd_zbEdWvkVvVI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=WWgaU_ugK4-IkQexyICoDQ&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=getmenu2%20%3Coption%3E&f=true

working php code..

```
$tech=$rs->GetMenu2('wo_tech',$login,$login_id,null,null,'onchange="this.form.submit()"' );
```

So there you go, this is how to add onchange event to GetMenu2